# want to populate datalist using json fetched from php using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I want to populate datalist using json fetched from php using jquery.

**HTML code** : index.php

```
<body>
    <input type='text' id="gpanel" name="gpanel" list='listid' required>
    <datalist id='listid'>
      //i want my options here
   </datalist>
</body>
```

**JQuery code** :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $.getJSON("php/ajax.php", function(return_data){
     $.each(return_data.data, function(key,value){
     $("#listid").append(
     "<option value="+value.gpanel+">"+"</option>" //gpanel is the title i want in the values
    ); 
  });
});
</script>
```

**php code** : ajax.php

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from active");//db name
while($rec = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
   $rows[] = $rec;
}
$json_row=json_encode($rows);
echo $json_row;
?>
```

I dont know where i did wrong! but the datalist is not populating as expected.

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: a populated datalist. the solution by @JoDev soved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JQuery you are trying to loop throught `return_data.data`... Use `$.each(return_data, function(key,value){` instead.

Or in PHP, add the `data` dimension :

```
$json_row=json_encode(array('data' => $rows));
```

Comment: Please downvoters, add comments to help us to improve our answers!

Comment: Thanks mate :) Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

So simple!

**HTML Code**

```
<form>
    <h3>Search :</h3><br>
    <input type="text" id="search" list="datalist">
    <datalist id="datalist"></datalist>
</form>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$("document").ready(()=>{
    $("#search").keyup(()=>{
        let list = $("#search").val();
        $("#datalist").empty();
        if(list!=""){
            $.getJSON("http://localhost/file.php?search="+list,(data)=>{
                $.each(data,(k,v)=>{     
                    $("#datalist").append("<option value="+v.gpanel+"></option>"); 
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP Code file.php**

```
$base = new PDO("mysql:host=URL;dbname=DATABASE_NAME","USER","PASSWORD");
$something = $_GET["search"];
$req = $base->prepare("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE Row_name LIKE '%".$something."%'");
$req->execute();
$tab = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($tab);
```

Comment: Remmeber to sanitize your input before performing a db query.